# Getting form elements to line up with submit button using display: inline-block and ems

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive form design; the whittled down code is below. Why doesn't the SEND button line up properly with the other input fields?

It's using a `margin-left:5em` which should line it up with the other input fields since the form labels also have a `width` of 5em, but no. Instead the button is offset to the left. What am I missing?

```css
label, input, textarea {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
label {width: 5em; text-align: right;}
input, textarea {width: 20em;}
input[type="submit"] {margin-left: 5em; width: 6em;}      
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="form1_name">Name:</label>
        <input id="form1_name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="first and last name" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="form1_email">Email:</label>
        <input id="form1_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="your email address" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="form1_message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="form1_message" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>
        <input value="SEND" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the UI at **pixel** level, you will see a whitespace between your labels and input fields.This whitespace is around **3px** wide and it doesn't come through your css. Why your submit button is not aligned with the above fields is because of that whitspace.

When you used **margin-left: 5em** on submit button, that extra whitespace is not added.So, to satisfy yourself, you can carry on what you have done so far, I mean, place that **submit** too in a div and use empty **label** tag before the input and remove the **margin-left** from the css

**OR**

you may follow Chandrakant's answer too.

**Update1:**

That whitespace is because of the new line for which you press "enter" key on your editor.So, to remove that whitespace without changing your css or using any magic numbers, you simply write those labels and inputs in the same line:

```
...
<div>
    <label for="form1_name">Name:</label><input id="form1_name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="first and last name" required="required" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="form1_email">Email:</label><input id="form1_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="your email address" required="required" />
</div>
...
```

Try it.

**Update2:** Main reason(button's default border)

The button is not aligned with the fields vertically because of the **border** property (by default) of the button.If you make the button's borders( in this case only **border-left : 0px** is required) to **0px** you will find the button aligned with the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How should I change my code so I don't have to use a magic number like 5.2em, and also so I don't have to add in a spacer empty label?

Comment: @NorthK That extra whitespace ;( you will never want.Updated the answer.Check it out

Comment: Thanks qwerty, I did try eliminating the space between labels and inputs, but the submit button still didn't line up. I'm marking your answer though because you explained what was going on. I decided to just go with vertically stacked labels and input fields instead-- much easier and works well for responsive designs.

Comment: @NorthK Thanks for accepting the answer.One more reason why the button is not aligned vertically with fields has been included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use below styling to your Input element this could work

```
display: block;
margin-left: 5.2em;
```

This is only for that send button